# does typescript automatically start express server when finish compile

Tags: typescript, tsc

When I run `yarn tsc`, the server directly starts on my port. I am not sure if this is intended behavior, but I want to see console to see outputs.

Here is package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "start:new": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"nodemon build/app.js\"",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"tsc -w\" \"node build/app.js\""
  },
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "outDir": "./build/",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

So when I do `yarn tsc`, my app is fully running. I tested with following.

First I killed the app and inspect the `port`

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:5000
```

and I get nothing. Then I run `yarn tsc`, and I see this:

```
node    80189 leoqiu   12u  IPv6 0x144eca87ffd0e50b      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

My understanding was that `tsc` only compiles the code, so I still need `concerently` to run the server. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it does, but I eventually just re-stared my computer. Then it worked! It is something with the `tsc` kept opening up the server directly.

Comment: I got the same issue. this should be investigated further. I know it's been a while but do you remember if you've used nodemon? which operating system were you using?